# Play Songs from Laptop to Phone

Tags: bluetooth

This is since a big issue that I wanna play songs from my laptop to my phone via bluetooth.

But the only solution I find that is play songs from mobile to laptop speakers.. but I want the opposite process to work on..

Because while I work on my laptop I want to listen the songs and control them from my laptop as well, but the speakers are pretty much away from my bed, so I wanna plug in the jack with my mobile and wanna play the track on my Laptop which will be listen to my phone via my laptop and phone bluetooth.

My Laptop is HP430 Notebook

And Phone is Xperia X8 (Android 2.1)

Please give me a solution, Thank you..

**I have solved this problem by buying  Belkin Bluetooth Music Receiver and then plug that in with my speakers port. Now my speakers are playing music over bluetooth connection.**

You can find this device in here: 
http://www.cnet.com/products/belkin-bluetooth-music-receiver-bluetooth-wireless-audio-receiver-series/

Comment: Instead of adding the solution to the question, feel free to post it as the answer. Self-answering is encouraged on SE. You may also accept your answer as well if any of current answers doesn't solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In PC:**

1. Open Windows Media Player
2. Switch to Libraries view. Then click the Organize drop-down menu, select Manage Libraries, and choose Music, Pictures, or Videos.
3. A Library Locations window will open, in which you can add other folders simply by clicking the Add button and browsing to the
   folders.
4. Now Click Stream select the option Automatically allow devices to play my media  click turn on media streaming [ if u get error
   "Windows Media Stream is not turned on" click "Windows Service
   Administrative tool" goto "windows media player network sharing
   service" double click on it In start type select Automatic]
5. connect your android via 
   bluetooth

**In Android:**

1. Launch [BubbleUpnp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp)
2. When it opens, tap the Devices tab at the bottom of the main
   interface. Assuming that your PC is on and connected to the network,
   and that streaming is enabled in WMP, your PC should show up in the
   Select Library list in the bottom half of the Devices menu.
3. Select your PC in the list, and tap the Library tab at the bottom;
   you’ll then be able to choose from the Music, Videos, Pictures, and
   Playlists folders available on the PC

Comment: thanks for the share.. I wish you could give me the solution earlier ! Though I bought a device by which I can just plug in the device with speakers and then the full sound box will be playing song with bluetooth sync. Exactly what I wanted..

Answer (score 2):

[image: SoundIt Google Chrome Extension]

I use **SoundIt**, it's a Google Chrome browser extension, go here: [SoundIt Chrome Browser Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/soundit/jpmlghikapcebilgkglhelbdipdibmgd?hl=en)

I use it when I watch online movies on my laptop, but want to listen to the movie on my Android cell phone with ear buds. You can also listen to music from your laptop as well, basicaly any audio thats coming from your computer, you can listen to on your cell phone.

**On Computer:** You need to use SoundIt on Google Chrome browser (to watch movies).

**On Cell Phone:** Any Android with an up - to - date Internet browser, I use Chrome.

It's using your wifi in your home to send the audio from the computer to the android cell phone. In my situation my laptop is not connected via wifi, but it's connected by ethernet, but thats no problem, because it's not using the computer to re-send the audio signal - it's using your wifi router ;)

Just follow the directions when you first run the SoundIt chrome extension, at some point it will tell you that you have to adjust windows firewall using the (SoundIt Enabler.exe) or you can do it manually via command prompt and some code they give you.

I suggest doing it manually, because I scanned the "Enabler.exe" and on some scanners it came us as 2 different malwares (supposidly). One that I can remember was an Adware and one other.

Why execute a .exe when you can just do it manually and know exactly what you're doing.

The above is so that SoundIt has permission send the audio signal from computer to your mobile device (android cell phone). In other words: It lets it be visible on the local network so other devices can connect to the computers sound output:)

It's very easy, at the end of configuration, it will give you a ip address like 192.168.1.9:7576 to then enter into the browser on your android cell phone.

Answer (score 1):

Once you pair the phone to your PC, you should be able to playback audio from you PC to the phone if your phone supports A2DP.

Comment: Most phones don't support the A2DP sink profile, only A2DP source (which means the phone can send audio over A2DP, but not receive).

Comment: For completeness: an [Android patch](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/98161/) (not really usable by end-users but it's a start) and a [Cyanogenmod request](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-3270) for A2DP sink support.

Answer (score 0):

It is not solution via bluetooth, but you can try application AirDroid:

[AirDroid on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en)

It has a lot features to synchronize your phone with your computer. You can play the music from your phone on laptop, just install this app on computer and on phone and sync them.

EDIT:
If you need to play music from laptop on your phone then try this app:

[SoundWire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.georgie.SoundWireFree)

Comment: what about laptop to phone...??

Comment: check the edit please.

Comment: Need soundwire app but with Bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

1. Your laptop and your have to be in the same network.
2. Install mediahouse upnp/dlna on your phone.
3. Laptop needs to be on and run the app.
4. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a USB cable to connect the laptop with the phone?

Comment: This is a possible solution. But how will he play the music? By double-clicking on the MP3 files (or other format) on the phone / SD card?

Answer (score 0):

[SoundWire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.georgie.SoundWireFree&hl=en), from the Play Store, may offer what you want. It uses a client/server setup on your local network instead of Bluetooth, however.

> SoundWire lets you send any music or audio ("what you hear now") from your Windows or Linux PC to your Android mobile devices. Use it as:
>
> - A remote speaker or wireless headphones
> - A way to listen to music and movies from your computer anywhere in your house or out on your deck.
> - A wireless extension of live audio from your PC-based music system